# elementary OS "freezes" on screen lock

Tags: release-freya, greeter, performance

I just installed elementary OS on a iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011), with AMD Radeon HD 6770M. It generally works well, except one thing:

---

When I lock the screen <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or leave the 
screen and then come back and the screen is off and locked.

When I unlock everything is unresponsive, or at least very slow.
When I press a button it takes several seconds before I react.

Sometimes I can just go standby, and back and everything is back to normal. Sometimes I have to reboot to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried restarting lightdm?? When you get you screen locked, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and you will enter in console mode, then log in and execute the next command.

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

if nothing happend then press again <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>  and check for an error message

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any idea for permanent solution for this issue? Because restart of lightdm means closing all programsand that the system becomes unusable...

Comment: If you have 1 user with running session `lightdm` you can `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` then login to user type `killall light-locker` then switch back `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F7` (and start `light-locker &` again in terminal.